# Atlaskit DropdownItem list is showing under app bar

Tags: reactjs, atlaskit

My DropdownItem lists positions are showing under my app bar. How could I show the DropDownItem lists over the app bar of my component. My current code is as below:

```
               <DropdownMenu trigger="User Base" >
                  <DropdownItemRadioGroup id="user_base">
                    <DropdownItemRadio
                      id="Total Base" defaultSelected
                    >
                      Total Base
                    </DropdownItemRadio>
                    <DropdownItemRadio
                      id="APP User"
                    >
                      App User
                    </DropdownItemRadio>
                    <DropdownItemRadio
                      id="USSD User"
                    >
                      USSD User
                    </DropdownItemRadio>
                    <DropdownItemRadio
                      id="EC Verified"
                    >
                      EC Verified
                    </DropdownItemRadio>
                    <DropdownItemRadio
                      id="new-user"
                    >
                      New User
                    </DropdownItemRadio>
                    <DropdownItemRadio
                      id="Self Registration"
                    >
                      Self Registration
                    </DropdownItemRadio>
                    <DropdownItemRadio
                      id="monthly-active"
                    >
                      Monthly Active
                    </DropdownItemRadio>
                  </DropdownItemRadioGroup>
                </DropdownMenu>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

style.css

```
div.css-xqfi6p {
margin-top: 8px;
}
```